# GNU Make: How to build a common lib as both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Tags: build, build-automation, static-libraries, gnu-make

I've got a project with a folder layout like:

```
/project_root
  /common-code-sources
    /common1
    /common2
    /...
  /prog-A-sources
  /prog-B-sources
  /prog-C-sources
```

Three executables need to be produced for Program A, B and C.  Each have a small amount of unique unique source code but mostly expect to statically link in functionality from the various `libCommonCodeN.a` files.

However, I need to build Program C and all it's required common code libraries with a specific set of compilation flags.  (In this case, 32-bit and with some optimizations disabled.)

This implies that the specific code under `common_sources` needed by Program C must be complied a second time with the correct flags.

I'm looking for ideas on how to best create a Makefile based build system to cover this situation.

I'm thinking the solution would involve a parallel output folders for the lib files and so-called "target-specific" `make` variables to guide the process, but I'm not sure of how to fit it all together.

**The Question:** How can I ensure that running `make` at the root of the project does the Right Thing when one of the `common-code` sources has changed?

That is: How can I just rebuild the two flavors of the particular `.a` in question and re-link the 3 executable files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is two approaches:

- Maintain single **Makefile** (you always can split Makefiles by **include** directive).
- Maintain own Makefiles for each subproject ([recursive make consider harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) approach).

In first case you have full control on dependencies... To make custom builds use:

```
  $ cat Makefile
...
ifeq '$(DEBUG)' 'yes'
  BUILD_DIR = debug
  CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_DEBUG)
else
  BUILD_DIR = release
  CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_OPTIM)
endif
...
  $ make DEBUG=yes
```

In second case mix first hint with:

```
  $ cat Makefile
...
ifeq '$(DEBUG)' 'yes'
  BUILD_DIR = debug
  MODULE_A_BUILD_DIR = ../module-A/_debug_build
  CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_DEBUG)
else
  BUILD_DIR = release
  MODULE_A_BUILD_DIR = ../module-A/_release_build
  CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_OPTIM)
endif

build: $(MODULE_A_BUILD_DIR)/libmodulea.a
    make -C $(MODULE_A_BUILD_DIR)/.. DEBUG=$(DEBUG)
...
```

You say all correctly in your question. Just do that logically consistent and don't  afraid))

So make **build** / **dist** path dependent on make flags or on target pattern:

```
ifneq '$(filter %-debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS))' ''
  BUILD_DIR = debug
  MODULE_A_BUILD_DIR = ../module-A/_debug_build
  CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_DEBUG)
  ...
endif
```